# nextcloud with ssl

Tags: ssl, nextcloud

I have nextcloud installed on a dedicated VPS running Ubuntu 19.10

```
nextcloud
sudo nextcloud.manual-install superuser XXXXXXXXX
sudo nextcloud.occ config:system:set trusted_domains 1 --value=<host name for server>
```

So far so good.  I can reach the site using http, but not using https.
How do I enable SSL?

`certbot` is not able to do it.

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/18/admin_manual/installation/source_installation.html#enabling-ssl) help?

Comment: No.  The Ubuntu default installation uses opaque (to me) web services.  I cannot find web logs, or configuration files.

I have stopped using ubuntu on the basis of them moving lots of their software to snap.  But I am stuck with it in this instance

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed via snap

> To install a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate, type:
>
> ```
> $ sudo nextcloud.enable-https lets-encrypt
> ```
>
> If you'd rather use a self-signed certificate, you can type:
>
> ```
> $ sudo nextcloud.enable-https self-signed
> ```

[Reference](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap/wiki/Enabling-HTTPS-(SSL,-TLS))

Comment: Self signed is not much use

Comment: How can I achieve that with non snap installation? (I mean, the manual install)